# error establishing database connection frequently in wordpress multisite

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wordpress

I am having a multisite network hosted on cloud. I came across the error "Error establishing a database connection" both in front and back end for the 2nd time.First time i just restarted the server and the problem was solved, now the issue came back again after couple of weeks. This time i didnt tried restarting instead am trying to find the cause. Since am planning to have more users in my site i think its not fair to keep on restarting the server.

I belive my wp-config is fine.At this stage i tried to test the db connection using following piece of code.

```
`<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', '*******', '*****');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>`
```

and added this file to my www folder. when i run the file shows "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)"
Can someone please help me with this...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is the file socket there?

Comment: @zerkms yes...it i there

Comment: better not to stick with `mysql_*` extension

Comment: Any idea is this issue with wp or problem in server side...sorry if question is dump am a newbie..?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue in wordpress, Just follow the below steps to fix the issue.

Add this code in **wp-config.php**

```
define(‘WP_ALLOW_REPAIR’, true);
```

yourdomain.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php

Click repair and optimize button to repair your database.

> Make sure you remove this line of code after you have fixed your
>   database connection error message.

If you still have this issues, contact your hosting provider. They will fix this easily.